# Disable converting epoch to date on Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime, validation

I have the following springboot request:

```
@Data
@ToString
public class OffsetDate {

  public OffsetDateTime time;
}
```

And my request goes:

```
{
  "time" : 20000101
}
```

Right now, that is being converted to date during serialization: 1970-01-01T05:33:20.101Z - which I don't want to happen.
I need to be able to specify the format and fail if it's invalid without custom annotations (request code is actually autogenerated from swagger yaml, hence I cannot modify the request).

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I am not sure what you expect. This is a Date/Time class. It's `toString()` method "converts" outputs a timestamp. If you need Epoch, then use a class that represents an epoch, or call a method that converts the time to an epoch. Did you read the Javadoc on `OffsetDateTime` before you made the decision to use it? Here's what's `toString()` does: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toString--

Comment: Thank you. It was not my decision to use OffsetDateTime. Basically, the goal is if the format I send on the request is NOT the same as 1970-01-01T05:33:20.101Z, it needs to throw an error - without me adding a custom annotation/serializer.

Comment: You might not have a choice. But you need to read the Javadoc to see if what you need is doable. If it is, the Javadoc should tell you how to make it work. And if it is not, then you need to figure out how to adapt it, or you need to tell the people who decided to go with this class that their decision won't work unless the make the necessary changes. The way I see it, it is working the way it is supposed to. Remember, the class' documentation states that it is "_a date-time with an offset from UTC/Greenwich **in the ISO-8601 calendar system**, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00._"